# The type is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-assembly

I've just begun incorporating a few projects from a partner office's solution into our solution.  The program is a C# winform application.

The program compiled and everything was going fine, but then yesterday I went to build again and out of nowhere it threw an error **"The type 'Namespace.MainFrameDisplay' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to assembly 'OtherAssembly, Version=1.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=52af1880d3cd7291"**  (As far as I can tell, OtherAssembly isn't used as a reference in the original project. There are compatibility issues between Assembly and OtherAssembly, adding OtherAssembly nets about 100 errors.)

As well as a related error **"Cannot implicitly convert type 'Namespace.MainFrameDisplay' to 'Namespace.MainFrameDisplay'  [c:\Dev\program\bin\debug\Assembly.dll]**

A snippet of psuedo-code for the error is:

```
private MainFrameDisplay _MainFrame;  //definition
_MainFrame = this.Mainframe;  // error is thrown here
_MainFrame.Parent.Controls.Add(_NotifyBar);
```

If I delete the definition, the error remains.
If I take out the line where the error is thrown, it compiles fine.  Even with calling the _MainFrame.Parent.

I've gone so far as to delete/remove this troublesome project and unzip/add a new copy of the original, but the problem remains.  Any thoughts, suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Well...........  Of course I figured this out right after posting.

( -_- )

So let's call this a tip for posterity.

In the code above, "this" references a base class, which is one of the other projects that I'm bringing into our solution.  I compared the references of the original base class project to my version, and sure enough I had accidentally included a Reference to "OtherAssembly" rather than "Assembly."   (Their real names are very similar.)

The incorrect reference didn't cause any problems in the base class, but caused a conflict in the derived class.  Switched, fixed, compiled successfully.